# List of all magic instructions in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a list of all the magic instructions in Ruby.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
# encoding: windows-1252
# warn_indent: false
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

I just got [one link](https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/58-magic-instructions.html) mentioning some of them.

Comment: The first one is a special-case, it specifies arguments to Ruby. Normally it's `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` with or without `-w` as preference dictates.

Comment: Please edit if you like... Or let me know!

Comment: @S.Goswami He's saying it's not Ruby-related, it's a shebang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you mention there has a link to [the Ruby source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_0/parse.y#L6687-L6690) where these are defined:

```
static const struct magic_comment magic_comments[] = {
    {"coding", magic_comment_encoding, parser_encode_length},
    {"encoding", magic_comment_encoding, parser_encode_length},
    {"frozen_string_literal", parser_set_compile_option_flag},
    {"warn_indent", parser_set_token_info},
# if WARN_PAST_SCOPE
    {"warn_past_scope", parser_set_past_scope},
# endif
};
```

One of these is gated based on a `#define`, so it may be a feature that's incomplete or yet to ship, perhaps held back for Ruby 2.7 or 3.0.